# How to upload a photo to facebook wall using graph api

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I am using graph api for uploading the photo.

I want to upload the picture to wall of user. I can't paste my local pc image to it.So Need to create first album and add image into it.

I am able to create an album.But I am getting an error on putting photo to an album.`Error is OAuthException", "message": "(#324)`.

Here is my url .I am doing in C#.net

```
https://graph.facebook.com/album_id/photos?access_token=generated access token&method=post&picture=D:\foldername\Image\flower.jpg&message=flower
```

Comment: i think the problem that you trying to send PATH of the image on your computer, not image itself, please provide some source code

Comment: I can't paste the code.Is there way to post image instead of path.

Comment: Not familiar with the API but common sense tells me that the value of `picture` should be the URL of valid picture e.g. `sURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/album_id/photos?access_token=generated access token&method=post&picture=" + Server.UrlEncode("http://www.somesite.com/flower.jpg") + "&message=flower";`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put @ in front of the file path, so it knows you're referencing to a file. And yes, you're doing it the right way. The Graph API supports only local file upload.

Comment: According to  Shadow and Observator,I have done but still have  same error.I know there is function called filupload=>true.But that is php function ,how to deals with C#.net

Comment: @ character mean that string is verbatim, not that is "file referecnce", [look c# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry, I've somehow overlooked that it's C# we're talking about.

If i stumble upon any examples, I'll be sure to post them here.

Also, the @ in PHP is by default used to supress error messages, but the Graph API uses it to reference a local file.

Answer (score 0):

It hard to give a concrete solution without the context though..

First look at the example from [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/). Note that image parameter name is source (not picture as in your url).

Second look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data) in second answer you will find method that help you to send image.

Just use it something like this:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();    
nvc.Add("access_token", "GENERATED TOKEN");    
nvc.Add("message", "MESSAGE TO SEND");    
HttpUploadFile("https://graph.facebook.com/album_id/photos",          
@"D:\foldername\Image\flower.jpg", "source", "image/jpeg", nvc);
```

Comment: Does I need to define method HttpUploadFile() or it is inbuild method we just need to call it.If yes what namespace does it required?

Comment: i have provided link to question about uploading files, look at second answer, code of method is the there

Comment: Hi Alexander,thank for your hepl.I will try ,if problem occure ,ask you.

Comment: Hi Alexander,I am still Having a problem.I tried that code.Now I am moving my direction.The thing is first have to create an album then add  photo to that album.Then pass a link or use picture or source attribute to post on user wall.I am getting an error when I am trying to send that .The error is "message": "(#100) FBCDN image is not allowed in stream.

Comment: unfortunatelly facebook doesn't allow to post images from fbcdn.net(it's where photos from album stored), it's weird but that the true( the only way you can send picture to wall is upload it to some picture(or may be you own) hosting, and then provide link for image from that hosting

Comment: Thanks Alexander.I think you are right.I don't see any other way.It is best to host own server.And used that link.Then I am able to do it.I know how to post picture to wall.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Alexander,Sorry for disturb you.I posted this question but not received the correct  answer that's why asking you.Do you have any idea about iframe?I want to add iframe to my facebook page.I read FBML that deprecated one.I am using C#.net for my project.Does I need to installed javascript sdk to do that.

Comment: I recommend you do not use deprecated api. Better to follow recomendations from facebook team and use JavaScript SDK, you do not need to install it, just reference it in header of you page, more info is [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)